# compilation error related to __builtin_bswap32

Tags: c, build, endianness, htonl

I m playing with open source which contains the following code

```
uint32_t addr = htonl(* (uint32_t *)RTA_DATA(rth));
if (htonl(13) == 13) {
    // running on big endian system
} else {
    // running on little endian system
    addr = __builtin_bswap32(addr);
}
```

It looks like it check if the system is a big endian or little endian with `if (htonl(13) == 13)`. is it correct? and could you please explain why the check this in this way? and why he use 13?

Also the `addr = __builtin_bswap32(addr);` cause a compilation problem **"undefined reference"**. Are there a solution to fix that? it looks like that function does not exist any more in the new versions of the gcc libs. is it correct?

EDIT:

The toolchain I use is  `toolchain-i386_gcc-4.1.2_uClibc-0.9.30.1`

for the options I used in the compilation:

- for the c to object compilation options:

  `-DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -I. -I/opt/lampp/htdocs/backfire/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/include -O2 -pipe -march=i486 -funit-at-a-time -fhonour-copts -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT`
- for the object to binary (linker)

  `-O2 -pipe -march=i486 -funit-at-a-time -fhonour-copts -D_GNU_SOURCE          -L/opt/lampp/htdocs/backfire/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/lib -L/opt/lampp/htdocs/backfire/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/lib -L/opt/lampp/htdocs/backfire/staging_dir/toolchain-i386_gcc-4.1.2_uClibc-0.9.30.1/lib -Wl,-rpath-link=/opt/lampp/htdocs/backfire/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/lib`

Comment: What compiler, and what compiler was the code actually written for?

Comment: it's  toolchain-i386_gcc-4.1.2_uClibc-0.9.30.1

Comment: And what compiler options?

Comment: for the object to binary (linker) `-O2 -pipe -march=i486 -funit-at-a-time -fhonour-copts -D_GNU_SOURCE          -L/opt/lampp/htdocs/backfire/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/lib -L/opt/lampp/htdocs/backfire/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/lib -L/opt/lampp/htdocs/backfire/staging_dir/toolchain-i386_gcc-4.1.2_uClibc-0.9.30.1/lib -Wl,-rpath-link=/opt/lampp/htdocs/backfire/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/lib`

Comment: for the c to object compilation options: `-DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -I.   -I/opt/lampp/htdocs/backfire/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/include -O2 -pipe -march=i486 -funit-at-a-time -fhonour-copts -D_GNU_SOURCE  -MT`

Comment: Don't see anything directly wrong there.

Comment: NO. the options are generated automatically by the platform OpenWRT.

Comment: Yes, just checking - there is a "-fno-builtin" or some such - and checking the obvious is always a good start...

Comment: I just tried adding `int x = __builtin_swap32(something);` into an existing program of mine, and it works fine. Of course, I have gcc 4.6.3, but I don't think that should make any huge difference, these have been part of gcc for quite a few years now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`htonl` converts a "host-order" number to network byte order.  Host order is whatever endianness you have on the system running the code.  Network byte order is big-endian.  If host-to-network is big-to-big, that means no change -- which is what `13` -> `13` would verify.  On the other hand, if host-to-network is small-to-big, that means you'll get swapping, so the least-significant byte `13` (least because changing it by 1 changes the overall number only by 1) would become most-significant-byte `13` (most because changing that byte by one changes the overall number by the largest amount), and `13` -> `(13 << 24)`.

`13` specifically is unimportant.  You could use any number, so long as its little-endian representation wasn't the same as its big-endian representation.  (`0` would be bad, because `0` byte-swapped is still `0`.  Same for `(65536 + 256)` as well, because the 32-bit representation is `00 01 01 00` in both big-endian and little-endian.

Note that there are also mixed-endian systems where for the 32-bit number `0x12345678`, you'd have bytes not in the order `12 34 56 78` (big-endian) or `78 56 34 12` (little-endian): `34 12 78 56` for one, I believe.  These systems aren't common, but they do still exist, and the code here wouldn't handle them correctly.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.0/gcc/Other-Builtins.html and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.0/gcc/Other-Builtins.html suggest `__builtin_bswap32` was added in gcc 4.3, so your gcc 4.1.2 toolchain wouldn't have it.